# Active Directory and PHP web Application - Fetching Display Name etc

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I've developed a basic web based app that connects to our Active Directory through PHP, using a login system.

It authenticates against AD and logs the user into a basic page that echos their username.

What I really want instead of echoing their username is to fetch either their AD first name and surname or their Display Name.

This is the code that I've got to authenticate against AD.

```
<?php
// Initialize session
session_start();

function authenticate($user, $password) {
    // Active Directory server
    $ldap_host = "...";

    // Active Directory DN
    $ldap_dn = "OU=...,DC=...,DC=...";

    // Active Directory user group
    $ldap_user_group = "...";

    // Active Directory manager group
    $ldap_manager_group = "...";

    // Domain, for purposes of constructing $user
    $ldap_usr_dom = "@...";

// connect to active directory
$ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host);


// verify user and password
if($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $user . $ldap_usr_dom, $password)) {
    // valid
    // check presence in groups
    $filter = "(sAMAccountName=" . $user . ")";
    $attr = array("memberof");
    $result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
    ldap_unbind($ldap);


    // check groups
    foreach($entries[0]['memberof'] as $grps) {
        // is manager, break loop
        if (strpos($grps, $ldap_manager_group)) { $access = 2; break; }


        // is user
        if (strpos($grps, $ldap_user_group)) $access = 1;
    }


    if ($access != 0) {
        // establish session variables
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['access'] = $access;
        return true;
    } else {
        // user has no rights
        return false;
    }


} else {
    // invalid name or password
    return false;
}
}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm new to this kind of stuff!

Answer (score 0):

You are so close to an answer. You just need to add a few more items to the attributes you are asking to be returned. You could change the following line

```
$attr = array("memberof");
```

to something like this this if you want more demographic info back from the directory server

```
$attr = array("cn", "displayName", "givenName", "sn", "mail", "memberof");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I've updated the array to use those attributes - although I'm unsure of how I'd pull this information out and display it. What I've got now is...

```
    <?php
// Initialize session
session_start();

function authenticate($user, $password) {
    // Active Directory server
    $ldap_host = " ";

    // Active Directory DN
    $ldap_dn = " ";

    // Active Directory user group
    $ldap_user_group = " ";

    // Active Directory manager group
    $ldap_manager_group = " ";

    // Domain, for purposes of constructing $user
    $ldap_usr_dom = " ";

// connect to active directory
$ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host);

// verify user and password
if($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $user . $ldap_usr_dom, $password)) {
    // valid
    // check presence in groups
    $filter = "(sAMAccountName=" . $user . ")";
    $attr = array("cn", "displayName", "givenName", "sn", "mail", "memberof");    
    $result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
    $displayname = $entries[0]['displayName'];
    ldap_unbind($ldap);

    // check groups
    foreach($entries[0]['memberof'] as $grps) {
        // is manager, break loop
        if (strpos($grps, $ldap_manager_group)) { $access = 2; break; }

        // is user
        if (strpos($grps, $ldap_user_group)) $access = 1;
    }

    if ($access != 0) {
        // establish session variables
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['access'] = $access;
        $_SESSION['displayName'] = $displayname;
        return true;
    } else {
        // user has no rights
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('You have no access to this page.')</script>";
        return false;
    }

} else {
    // invalid name or password
        return false;

}
}
?>
```